# Скрипт запуска случайного файла из случайной папки

Tags: cmd, bat

*есть уже код который умеет открывает случайный файл*

```
:a
echo off

tree /F
echo ---------------------

timeout 2 > NUL

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set i=0
for %%f in (*.*) do (
    set file!i!=%%f
    set /a i+=1
)
set /a n=%random% %% %i%
set file=!file%n%!
start "" "%file%

echo %file%

pause > NUL
goto a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: Create numbered list of files in a temporary file
set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0_fileList_%time::=.%.txt"
dir /b /s /a-d %1 | findstr /n "^" >"%tempFile%"

:: Count the files
for /f %%N in ('type "%tempFile%" ^| find /c /v ""') do set cnt=%%N

call :openRandomFile

:: Delete the temp file
del "%tempFile%"

exit /b

:openRandomFile
set /a "randomNum=(%random% %% cnt) + 1"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (
  'findstr "^%randomNum%:" "%tempFile%"'
) do start "" "%%B"
exit /b
```

Скрипт запускает случайные файлы начиная от текущей директории. Но можно задать нужную директорию, используя первый аргумент, например `start.bat "d:\dir\"`

Оригинал скрипта [здесь](https://superuser.com/questions/872048/opening-random-file-from-folder-and-subfolders-with-batch-script-windows-7).